# How to let short content pages reach the bottom of the browser window and then a footer should appear

Tags: html, css, layout, footer

In this case, I've developed a CSS code for this web application ..and sometimes the resulting data is too small and the footer of the site appears in the middle of the page and looks odd.

I'd like to push that whitespace of the background to the browser's bottom and then followed by a footer. AND if the page is long, that text won't get overlapped by the footer.

**Can someone help me out with this code right here?**

I've been trying to use some of the codes I found on this page:http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page  which talks about pretty much the same issue, but I can't get it completely done:
**What am I doing wrong ?**

```
@charset "utf-8";
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    height:100%; /* needed for container min-height */
    }
.spacer {
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0.1em;
}
.spacer_left {
    clear: left;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0.1em;
}
hr {
    height: 1px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    border: 0;
    color: #ccc;
    background: #ccc;
}
#container {
    position:relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
    height:auto !important; /* real browsers */
    height:100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/
    min-height:100%; /* real browsers */

    width: 1160px;  /* width of the site ! */
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    text-align: left;
}
/* Context Bar */ 
h1#contexto {
    background:url('../images/menubarbg2.png');
    width:1160px;
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:10px;
    visibility: inherit;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}
#header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    height:70px;
}
h1#titulo {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0;

}
#content {

 margin: -15px 20px 0 20px;
 /*padding: -6px 5px 20px 5px;*/
 padding:1em 1em 5em; /* bottom padding for footer */

}
div#content.columns {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#content abbr, #content acronym {
    cursor: help;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
#content ul {
    list-style-type: square; 
}
#content ul li, #content ol li {
    margin: 0 0 0.4em 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
#content blockquote {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

#footer  
{
 margin: 0;
 height: -30px;
 padding: 5px;
 clear: both;
 bottom:0; 
 position:relative;
}
```

**UPDATE: THE SOLUTION**

```
@charset "utf-8";
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height:100%; /* needed for footer positioning*/
}
.spacer {
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0.1em;
}
.spacer_left {
    clear: left;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0.1em;
}
hr {
    height: 1px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    border: 0;
    color: #ccc;
    background: #ccc;
}
#container {
    position:relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
    min-height: 100%;/* needed for footer positioning*/
    height: auto !important;/* needed for footer positioning*/
    height: 100%;/* needed for footer positioning*/
    margin: 0 auto -30px;/* needed for footer positioning*/
    width: 1160px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    text-align: left;
}
#header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    height:70px;
}
h1#titulo {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0;
}
h1#contexto {
    background:url('../images/menubarbg2.png');
    width:1160px;
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:10px;
    visibility: inherit;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}
#content {
    margin: -15px 20px 30px 20px; /* needed for footer positioning*/
}
div#content.columns {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#content abbr, #content acronym {
    cursor: help;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
#content ul {
    list-style-type: square;
}
#content ul li, #content ol li {
    margin: 0 0 0.4em 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#content blockquote {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}
#footer, .push /* needed for footer positioning*/ {
    padding: 5px;
    clear: both;
    position:absolute;/* needed for footer positioning*/
    bottom:0;/* needed for footer positioning*/
    height: -30px;/* needed for footer positioning*/
    width:1150px;
}
```

Comment: Please review the update on this very post. The correction of the code has been done and it works, so I'm posting it here, just in case anyone wants to see the difference between the old css and the fix.
Thanks to users Yongho and Ricebowl for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a "sticky footer" by having the body height equal to the height of your browser window (ie: setting the height to 100%), then forcing the footer to be at the bottom of whatever height your browser window is.

CSS:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#footer {
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 height:60px;
 background:#ccc;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html><body>

 text here text here

 <div id="footer">
  Im in the footer and bottom of the page!
 </div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Well, I don't know how. But I just did edit a bit my code and it worked, with your suggestions. It seems like it was the same thing I was doing before, but for some reason didn't work. Thank you for your kind help.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't tried thiS approach in a while, but from memory -and it might've been a doctype problem- I seem to recall that this causes the footer to always be on-screen, but also to overlap the content that overflows the browser's lower border, when scrolled. Though I'm not down-voting, because I can't remember for sure.

Comment: You could solve the overlapping problem with padding-bottom on the body, I guess. But you'd want the footer to be pushed down to the bottom of the content, bellow the scroll... I'm not confident on how to get that, but perhaps using min-height instead of height.

Comment: The solution to this specific case, was added to the content of the question. Thank you for helping !